# Weird problem with calling functions in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, object

I'm just trying to write a code for myself and I have problem with calling a specific function in my code and it is weird because I already have 2 more functions just like this one and they do their job correctly check it out

```
import random

name = ("aghayan","jafari","panahi","kashkool")
word = random.choice(names)
dash_guess = "-" * len(word)
guesses_left = 5
class hangman():
    def Entrance():
        print(" one of your python classmates was an undercover cop and set a ")
        print(" trap for our Boss Mohammad Esmaili!'THE CARTEL KING' so they arrest him .")
        print(" we just need that snitch name and your the only person of that")
        print(" class that we have access to , so your going to tell us the snitch")
        print(" name or i will hang you my self and you got only 5 chances to ")
        print(" tell me his or hers name or you'll die")
        print()
        def repeat():

            your_choice =input(" so will you help me or you want to die ? 'yes' or 'no' : ")

            if your_choice == "yes":
                print("Good it seems you have someone waiting for you and you want to ")
                print("see him/her again , you better be telling the truth or i,ll go ")
                print("and pay a visit to your love")
                core_game(guess)


            elif your_choice == "no":
                print("ok good choice , it will be my pleasure to kill you ")
                print("________      ")
                print("|      |      ")
                print("|      0      ")
                print("|     /|\     ")
                print("|     / \     ")
                print("|             ")
                print("Adios my friend , i hope you rest in peace in HELL")
                exit()

            else :
                print(" it seems the noose tightens around your neck and its getting")
                print(" hard to talk but i just need 'yes' or 'no' for answer")
                repeat()
        repeat()
    Entrance() 
    def core_game(guess):
         while guesses_left > 0 and not dash_guess == word:
             guess = input("so tell me that snitch name letter by letter : ")
         if guess != 1:
             print("NOPE , i need you to spell the name of that rat")

    core_game(guess)




game = hangman()
```

It's not complete but the question is when I enter 'yes' it should take the program to def core_game() but it give me error that " core_game is not defined ".

Comment: are the indentation in your code correct? because here it doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This section is your problem:

```
def core_game(guess):
     while guesses_left > 0 and not dash_guess == word:
         guess = input("so tell me that snitch name letter by letter : ")
     if guess != 1:
         print("NOPE , i need you to spell the name of that rat")

core_game(guess)
```

**The lack of indent on the last line drops you out of the class definition.** In other words, you're calling `core_game` from the *global* scope (where it's not defined) rather than from within the class (where it is defined).

Python is picky with indenting and formatting; I'd advise you to take some time to learn how to correctly format your code for Python, which will not only help you reduce errors but will also make your code significantly easier for you and anyone else to read.

Your solution is to *remove* the `core_game(guess)` call entirely. You don't need it, because you're already calling `Entrance()`, and that calls `core_game` at the correct points for you.

You've also got another issue - your `core_game` method has a `guess` parameter, but it's not necessary and it's making it hard for you to call it correctly:

```
def core_game(guess):
    while guesses_left > 0 and not dash_guess == word:
        # On this line, you're overwriting the value of the guess parameter
        # before you've actually read it. Hence, you don't actually
        # need that parameter at all.
        guess = input("so tell me that snitch name letter by letter : ")
    if guess != 1:
        print("NOPE , i need you to spell the name of that rat")
```

And, where you call it:

```
if your_choice == "yes":
    print("Good it seems you have someone waiting for you and you want to ")
    print("see him/her again , you better be telling the truth or i,ll go ")
    print("and pay a visit to your love")

    # At this point, guess is not defined, so you're not passing anything
   # to the core_game function.
    core_game(guess)
```

Given that (a) you're not passing anything, and (b) you never actually use the parameter, you can just remove it.

After all the suggestions above, here's how your code looks:

```
import random

name = ("aghayan", "jafari", "panahi", "kashkool")
word = random.choice(names)
dash_guess = "-" * len(word)
guesses_left = 5

class Hangman():
    def entrance(self):
        print(" one of your python classmates was an undercover cop and set a ")
        print(" trap for our Boss Mohammad Esmaili!'THE CARTEL KING' so they arrest him .")
        print(" we just need that snitch name and your the only person of that")
        print(" class that we have access to , so your going to tell us the snitch")
        print(" name or i will hang you my self and you got only 5 chances to ")
        print(" tell me his or hers name or you'll die")
        print()

        def repeat():
            your_choice =input(" so will you help me or you want to die ? 'yes' or 'no' : ")

            if your_choice == "yes":
                print("Good it seems you have someone waiting for you and you want to ")
                print("see him/her again , you better be telling the truth or i,ll go ")
                print("and pay a visit to your love")
                core_game(guess)


            elif your_choice == "no":
                print("ok good choice , it will be my pleasure to kill you ")
                print("________      ")
                print("|      |      ")
                print("|      0      ")
                print("|     /|\     ")
                print("|     / \     ")
                print("|             ")
                print("Adios my friend , i hope you rest in peace in HELL")
                exit()

            else:
                print(" it seems the noose tightens around your neck and its getting")
                print(" hard to talk but i just need 'yes' or 'no' for answer")
                repeat()

        repeat()

    def core_game(self):
        while guesses_left > 0 and not dash_guess == word:
            guess = input("so tell me that snitch name letter by letter : ")
        if guess != 1:
            print("NOPE , i need you to spell the name of that rat")

game = Hangman()
game.entrance()
```

I've also applied some stylistic corrections and corrected the indentation here. You've got a logic bug left, as well, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you to figure out.

Comment: i replied to you in an answer please check it out

Comment: Keep the answers section free for answers to your questions, @aliaghayan - you had it right by replying to me in a comment to start with. You shouldn't be getting the _same_ error after what I've suggested here, but you do have a separate issue. Let me edit my answer and I'll address that as well.

Comment: i really appreciate your help and i'll check it out and report it to you , thanks a lot

Comment: i found two problems first was " name " definition at beginning of the program witch had to be " names " and the other one was at the def Entrance() witch it needed to add an arguments that you added to the bottom of the code game.Entrance() but now i have three more errors

Comment: The "three more errors" are part of your logic bug, I imagine. Try to figure them out; if you can't, ask a new question.

Comment: and what is the reason that i have to insert an argument in entrance or it wouldn't work ? and still core_game is not defined and it says that there is some thing wrong with both repeat() i used and if just delete them the program wont even run

Comment: That... would be me, missing an argument :) Class methods in Python must have a `self` argument to refer to the class instance before any other arguments.

Comment: how is it possible that mine would work without argument and yours won't work ?

Comment: Because you called it from within the class definition, whereas I moved that to an instance call